# How can I get both links and values from a column with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA project that is configured to return links for some columns that are linked to other tables.

The row value is an ID that acts as foreign key to another table, therefore having the links is correct and works for my PUT requests, but in some cases, I need to get the value instead of the link, to avoid having to call the link for each object returned, to know the same value the table already has.

Is there a way to do it?

E.g.:

Requesting matches returns a collection of these.

```
  {
    "homeTeamGoals": 1,
    "awayTeamGoals": 0
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/matches/31102"
      },
      "match": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/matches/31102"
      },
      "homeTeam": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/matches/31102/homeTeam"
      },
      "awayTeam": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/matches/31102/awayTeam"
      }
    }
  }
```

I need to create a standings table with 200 matches. In the current state, I need to take my 200 matches and make 2 calls in each one, to the homeTeam and awayTeam to know who played and then make all my calculations.

What I need is to get the value from the column (which is an ID) so I can only make 1 call to get the matches and I already know who played. If I need to resolve the team, I will make 20 calls when I have my final list, instead of the 400 I have to now.

Comment: why don't you create queries and return DTOs that fit your needs? Have a look here : https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/08/29/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use projections. With projections you can choose which fields and child mapping you want in the result object. Refer - 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts

Comment: Took me a couple of days but that did it. And boy this is going to make my life easier haha. Thanks